# Create Dynamic Web Control in c# desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I just want to create multiple web control using c# in visual studio. I have written the code for that but it create only once, I think it show the control created at the last in the loop.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MDMScreenSharing
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private List<Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser> geckowebbrouser;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 20, 20);
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int inputNumber =5;
            geckowebbrouser = new List<Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= inputNumber; i++)
            {
                int j = 1;
                String wbname = "br" + i;

                Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser gw = new Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser();
                gw.Width = 200;
                gw.Height = 200;
                gw.Parent = panel1;
                gw.Name = wbname;
                gw.Location = new Point(gw.Width, panel1.Bottom + (i * 30));
                gw.Navigate("http://192.168.1.162:8080");
                geckowebbrouser.Add(gw);
                this.Controls.Add(gw);
                j = j*gw.Width;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will show the web control created at the last. I think the program should be more dynamic for that. What am I doing wrong?

The form output, that show only once.

[image]

with the new addition of code i have code that one of you provided. the code is

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MDMScreenSharing
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private List<Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser> geckowebbrouser;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           // this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
           // this.AutoSize = true;
            //this.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 20, 20);
           // this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(602, 395);
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int inputNumber =4;
           geckowebbrouser = new List<Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser>();
           for (int i = 1; i <= inputNumber; i++)
           {

               String wbname = "br" + i;
               Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser gw = new Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser();
               gw.Parent = flowLayoutPanel1;

               gw.Width = 200;
               gw.Height = 200;

               gw.Name = wbname;
               gw.Navigate("http://192.168.1.162:8080");
               geckowebbrouser.Add(gw);
               flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(gw);

           }

        }

    }
}
```

but the problem in this case only one browser window navigate the page.
like this

[image]

as you can see.

Comment: What happen if you set location after adding it to `Form.Controls`?

Comment: I think there are multiple overlapping web browser controls being added. Are you sure your point co-ordinate formula is working as expected?

Comment: nothing happen if i set the location after adding the control to form.

Comment: i don't think show. i am actually confuse in the point co-ordinate. i have tried multiple time.

Comment: What is `panel1`? You set `gw.Parent = panel1;` maybe it force the web browser to be inside `panel1`

Comment: yes i have put the web browser in to the panel1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think better approach will be using `FlowLoayoutPanel` so that you don't have to handle the position of each new control.

Go like this:

Add the `FlowLayoutPanel` through visual designer from toolbox.
Then on your `designer.cs` you should automatically have:

```
// 
// flowLayoutPanel1
// 
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(602, 395);
this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
```

FormLoad event:

```
private void Form1_Load ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    int inputNumber = 5;
    geckowebbrouser = new List<Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser>();
    for ( int i = 1; i <= inputNumber; i++ )
    {
        int j = 1;
        String wbname = "br" + i;
        var gw = new Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser();
        gw.Width = 300;
        gw.Height = 300;
        gw.Name = wbname;
        geckowebbrouser.Add(gw);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(gw);

        gw.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

**Update**

The only difference from the `WebBrowser` implementation is that you need to call the `Navigate` method after you've added the control to the panel. Check the updated code above.

I have tested with default `Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser` control too, and it's working just fine too:

[image]

Comment: thank your @Evcimen. but the problem is still same. the navigation of link shows only once. i want to create multiple web control that show different navigation. in this solution only first control shows the navigation not remains.

Comment: will you send me the code also.. if you don't mind. i have also tried that but  the default WebBrowser control is based on the internet explorer and it not support the streaming.

Comment: just substitute the `Skybound.Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser` with `WebBrowser`, that's the code I have too. I'll try to get it working with gecko browser too if I can find the library:)

Comment: i can send you if you provide your email id.

Comment: Email sharing is not a sympathic behaviour here, share a link yo the library in your question.

Comment: your need Skybound.GeckoFX.bin.v1.9.0.0 at this link... https://code.google.com/p/geckofx/downloads/detail?name=Skybound.GeckoFX.bin.v1.9.0.0.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: and for using this tool you have to also download the additional library to your bin/debug folder... that is .xulrunner-1.9.1.2.en-US.win32 and the link is https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/xulrunner/releases/1.9.1.2/runtimes/

Comment: this is also work for me but it show remaining navigation after a long time.. i think it is because of same socket. i will try for this at different sockets. thank you...